# Electron + Angular = no local files?

Tags: javascript, angular, express, electron

My issue is hard to explain, but I'll try - 
I've got electron error `Not allowed to load local resource` when trying to playback `mp3` file from the directory of application.

That happens because I'm using **Webpack** for development and **Express** server for production to run my apps (Express is used due to some Angular routing features).

This is part of my `electron-main.js` -

```
function createWindow() {
    win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1500,
    height: 900,
    resizable: true,
    center: true,
    autoHideMenuBar: true,
    icon: path.join(__dirname, 'static', 'note.ico')
  });

   if (DEBUG) {
     // Loading from Webpack
     win.loadURL(`http://localhost:4200`);
     win.webContents.openDevTools();
   }
   else {
     // Loading from Express-server
     const server = require("../server");
     win.loadURL(`http://localhost:3333`);
   }
```

server.js

```
let path = require('path');
let express = require('express');
let app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist', 'index.html'));
});

app.listen(3333);
```

But when I tried to set

```
win.loadURL(url.format({
    pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'),
    protocol: 'file:',
    slashes: true
  }));
```

I've got my `mp3` playback.

So I understand that local files can be accessed only when `protocol: 'file:'`, not `http:`
App structure should be similar -

```
(root folder)
--app.exe (whatever)
--mp3
  --1.mp3
  --2.mp3
  --3.mp3
  ...
```

Is there a workaround? Maybe I can use Express to get my files?

Answer (score 1):

The only workaround I've found is to create additional hidden window using `file:` protocol like this

```
hiddenWindow = new BrowserWindow({
  show: false
});

hiddenWindow.loadURL(url.format({
  pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'hidden.html'),
  protocol: 'file:',
  slashes: true
}));
```

and init it's functions using `ipcRenderer` and `ipcMain`.